# How to get index element in array with two the same elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "ab", "gh"];
```

Now, i have `"ab"` on position 0 and 3. I want to have index element only on position 3. I don't want `"ab"` on position 0. How can i get index element only on position 3? Please help.

---

second option:
what if i have 5 elements or more? like this:

`var array = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "ab", "gh", "ab", "kl", "ab", "ab"];`

and now i want to have element on position 5?

Comment: with `lastIndexOf` or with `indexOf` and a start value greater than the value of the first one

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
var lastIndex = 0;
var checkValue = 'ab';
var array = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "ab", "gh"];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] == checkValue) lastIndex = i;
};
```

In simple word:

- `lastIndex` is the variable that contains the last matching index;
- `checkValue` is the value you are looking for in the array;
- the for cycle loop in the whole array and check if the actual item is equal to the checking value. If yes, update the `lastIndex` var.

Comment: Krystian: if you have other scenarios/requirements you need to be met, please consider updating your question (use the 'edit' link beneath the tags to the question to do so); that way all the answers will try to offer solutions to meet all your requirements, or explain why they might be impossible or inadvisable (depending on the additional requirements).

Answer (score 0):

I have maked function that can search anything from array

```js
var array = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "ab", "gh"];

function search(search, arr, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (search === arr[i]) {
      callback(arr[i], i, arr);
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

search('ab', array, function(item, i) {
  alert(item + " : " + i);
});

// or use this 

Array.prototype.search = function(search, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (search === this[i]) {
      callback(this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
  return -1;
};

array.search('ab', function(item, i) {
  alert(item + " : " + i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
function findAll (needle, haystack) {

    // we iterate over the supplied array using
   // Array.prototype.map() to find those elements
   // which are equal to the searched-for value
  // (the needle in the haystack):
    var indices = haystack.map(function (el, i) {
        if (el === needle) {
            // when a needle is found we return the
            // index of that match:
            return i;
        }
    // then we use Array.prototype.filter(Boolean)
    // to retain only those values that are true,
    // to filter out the otherwise undefined values
    // returned by Array.prototype.map():
    }).filter(Boolean);

    // if the indices array is not empty (a zero
    // length is evaluates to false/falsey) we
    // return that array, otherwise we return -1
    // to behave similarly to the indexOf() method:
    return indices.length ? indices : -1;
}

var array = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "ab", "gh"],
       needleAt = findAll('ab', array); // [0, 3]
```